TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module when debugging in local machine
I am using dynamic import in my react typescript project like this:
import { LanguageDescription } from "@codemirror/language";

export const languages: LanguageDescription[] = [
  LanguageDescription.of({
    name: "latex",
    extensions: [
      "tex",
      "sty",
      "Rtex",
      "rtex",
      "pstex",
      "pstex_t",
      "gin",
      "fontspec",
      "pygstyle",
      "pygtex",
      "ps_tex",
      "ltx",
    ],
    load: () => {
      debugger;
      return import("./latex").then((m) => {
        debugger;
        return m.latex();
      });
    },
  }),
];

the latex/index.ts file was in the same folder, when I debugging this file in my local machine, shows error:
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://dev-tex.example.com/src/component/common/editor/foundation/languages/latex/index.ts?t=1723298528347

when I publish this project to production, it works fine. why this dynamic import did not work in local machine? I have read this issue https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/11804 and tried to disable the adblocker but did not fixed this issue. does anyone facing the same issue? the vite version is "vite": "^4.5.3". Also tried like this:
var result = import("@/component/common/editor/foundation/languages/latex/index").then((m) => {
        debugger;
        return m.latex();
      });

